# User show route and showing user with query string rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently on my routes file

```
  resources :users, only: [:show, :index, :update] do
    get :impersonate, on: :member
  end
```

i have user resource and showing users as /users and a single user as

```
user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                users#show
```

but as per need i want to show a user as

```
/users?q=test@test.com
```

in my show controller am setting user as

```
  def set_user
    @user ||= EvercamUser.find(params[:id])
  end
```

and i tried to create a route as

```
match "/users?q=" => "users#show", :via => [:get]
```

but when ever i try `/users?=test@test.com` it dont even go to `show` method of `user` controller, why is it so?
I want to show the user in both ways.
`/users/19` or `/users?q=test@test.com`

```
                     root GET    /                                   dashboard#index
         new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)            devise/sessions#new
             user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)            devise/sessions#create
     destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)           devise/sessions#destroy
            user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)           passwords#create
        new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)       passwords#new
       edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)      passwords#edit
                          PATCH  /users/password(.:format)           passwords#update
                          PUT    /users/password(.:format)           passwords#update
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)             registrations#cancel
        user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                    registrations#create
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)            registrations#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)               registrations#edit
                          PATCH  /users(.:format)                    registrations#update
                          PUT    /users(.:format)                    registrations#update
                          DELETE /users(.:format)                    registrations#destroy
         impersonate_user GET    /users/:id/impersonate(.:format)    users#impersonate
                    users GET    /users(.:format)                    users#index
                     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                users#show
                          PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                users#update
                          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                users#update
            merge_cameras GET    /cameras/merge(.:format)            cameras#merge
                  cameras GET    /cameras(.:format)                  cameras#index
                          POST   /cameras(.:format)                  cameras#create
               new_camera GET    /cameras/new(.:format)              cameras#new
              edit_camera GET    /cameras/:id/edit(.:format)         cameras#edit
                   camera GET    /cameras/:id(.:format)              cameras#show
                          PATCH  /cameras/:id(.:format)              cameras#update
                          PUT    /cameras/:id(.:format)              cameras#update
                          DELETE /cameras/:id(.:format)              cameras#destroy
    camera_share_requests GET    /share-requests(.:format)           camera_share_requests#index
                          POST   /share-requests(.:format)           camera_share_requests#create
 new_camera_share_request GET    /share-requests/new(.:format)       camera_share_requests#new
edit_camera_share_request GET    /share-requests/:id/edit(.:format)  camera_share_requests#edit
     camera_share_request GET    /share-requests/:id(.:format)       camera_share_requests#show
                          PATCH  /share-requests/:id(.:format)       camera_share_requests#update
                          PUT    /share-requests/:id(.:format)       camera_share_requests#update
                          DELETE /share-requests/:id(.:format)       camera_share_requests#destroy
                snapshots GET    /snapshots(.:format)                snapshots#index
                          POST   /snapshots(.:format)                snapshots#create
             new_snapshot GET    /snapshots/new(.:format)            snapshots#new
            edit_snapshot GET    /snapshots/:id/edit(.:format)       snapshots#edit
                 snapshot GET    /snapshots/:id(.:format)            snapshots#show
                          PATCH  /snapshots/:id(.:format)            snapshots#update
                          PUT    /snapshots/:id(.:format)            snapshots#update
                          DELETE /snapshots/:id(.:format)            snapshots#destroy
                  vendors GET    /vendors(.:format)                  vendors#index
                          POST   /vendors(.:format)                  vendors#create
               new_vendor GET    /vendors/new(.:format)              vendors#new
              edit_vendor GET    /vendors/:id/edit(.:format)         vendors#edit
                   vendor GET    /vendors/:id(.:format)              vendors#show
                          PATCH  /vendors/:id(.:format)              vendors#update
                          PUT    /vendors/:id(.:format)              vendors#update
                          DELETE /vendors/:id(.:format)              vendors#destroy
                          PATCH  /vendors(.:format)                  vendors#update
            vendor_models GET    /models(.:format)                   vendor_models#index
                          POST   /models(.:format)                   vendor_models#create
         new_vendor_model GET    /models/new(.:format)               vendor_models#new
        edit_vendor_model GET    /models/:id/edit(.:format)          vendor_models#edit
             vendor_model GET    /models/:id(.:format)               vendor_models#show
                          PATCH  /models/:id(.:format)               vendor_models#update
                          PUT    /models/:id(.:format)               vendor_models#update
                          DELETE /models/:id(.:format)               vendor_models#destroy
                          GET    /models/load.vendor.model(.:format) vendor_models#load_vendor_model
                   models PATCH  /models(.:format)                   vendor_models#update
                          DELETE /models(.:format)                   vendor_models#delete
                      map GET    /map(.:format)                      dashboard#map
                      kpi GET    /kpi(.:format)                      dashboard#kpi
                no_access GET    /no_access(.:format)                home#no_access
         cloud_recordings GET    /cloud_recordings(.:format)         snapshots#index
                          GET    /users?q=(.:format)                 users#show
```

PS: i dont want to use any gem for this.

Comment: Could you add the complete output of `rake routes` please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are saying is that if the `users#index` action is called with `params[:q]`, then use params[:q] to find a user by email, and if you find one, redirect to the show page.

```
def index
  if params[:q] && (user = User.where(email: params[:q]))
    redirect_to user_path(user)
  else
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`q=` is just a parameter which can be added to every URL.

So you just need the route which links to `/users` and add then a parameter to it.

```
get 'users' => 'users#show', as: :show_users
```

Now if you generate a link with the path helpers, you just have to pass the parameters to it.

For example: `show_users_path(q: 'johndoe@example.com')`

And you should then be able to use the email with `params[:q]`.

To set the user I would recommend you the following:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: :show

  def show
  end

  private

  def set_user
    if id = params[:id]
      @user = EvercamUser.find(id)
    elsif email = params[:q]
      @user = EvercamUser.find_by(email: email)
    end

    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound unless @user.present?
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    # Do something if no user was set
  end
end
```

This looks a bit complicated but is in my opinion the best best solution for your case. I will explain it shortly:

1. It tries to set user by an ID
2. If it doesn't find an ID, it tries to set one by an email address
3. After that it will raise the Rails exception `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` but JUST if no user was set.
4. In the rescue block you should redirect the user to the root page or back

BTW `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` will also be raised if the `.find` method doesn't find a record with the ID in the database.

Comment: after doing this i also done   def set_user
    `if params[:q]
      @user = EvercamUser.find_by_email(params[:q])
    else
      @user = EvercamUser.find(params[:id])
    end
  end`
now on server side q: is passing but user isnt setting as params[:q] when i do /users?q=test@test.com

Comment: Hi @JunaidFarooq! I've updated my answer. Please ask if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

**ROUTES**

replace this

```
match "/users?q=" => "users#show", :via => [:get]
```

to this

```
get "users" => "users#show"
get "users/:q" => "users#show"
```

and

**CONTROLLER**

```
def set_user
    @user ||= EvercamUser.find(:all, :conditions => ["id = ? or email = ?", params[:q], params[:q]])
end
```

Comment: i dont want /users/:q what i want is `/users?q=:email` not /users/:q

Comment: you have asked for both /users?q=:email and /users/id should route to users#show page right for that you can change :id to :q in your routes and params then it will work for both the cases.since you cant change the query string q to id.

Comment: `get "users/:q" => "users#show"` cant it be `"/users?q=" => "users#show",` ?

Comment: no in routes you cant write that. thatsy am asking you to change your routes like i mentioned.then it ll work as you asked

Comment: suppose in params[:q] there is an email "test@test.com"
how can you find then ?
`@user ||= EvercamUser.find(params[:q])` how this will find a user wil email? on FIND?

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your question.please try that

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is "/users?q=" part.
Try yourself again with follow code:

```
match "/users/:q" => "users#show", :via => [:get]
```

In your controller:

```
def set_user
  @user ||= EvercamUser.find_by_q(params[:q])
end
```

(with q is a column in ) users tables.

Comment: but i want the url to be `/users?q=:email` not /users/:q

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure and if I'm wrong someone can correct me but I don't think you can have a path like `/users?anything` as a route.

It's just a hunch but think what would happen if you tried to create a path with some additional attributes? you would end up having something like `/users?something?params` and how would rails deal with such a path? Behaviour of it is probably undefined and therefore invalid.

Others already gave you an alternative so I won't repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `/users?q=test@test.com` will send the request to the *index* action (as opposed to the `show` action). You just need to be able to handle the query string when it hits the controller:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController 
   def index
      if params[:q]
         @users = User.where email: params[:q]
      else
         @users = User.all
      end
   end
end
```

I presume you're using the above for some sort of "search" functionality; if so, the above code will allow you to populate the `index` view with the `@users` var:

```
#app/views/users/index.html.erb
<% @users.each do |user| %>
   <%= user.email %>
<% end %>
```

You can use the link as follows:

```
<%= link_to "Users", users_path(q: "email@email.com") %>
```

... if you wanted to make a button:

```
<%= button_to "Users", users_path, method: :get, params: { q: "email@email.com" } %>
```

--

If you want to use that url to display a *specific* user, you'll need to send the request to the `show` action (standard functionality) (`url.com/users/:id`), which is standard if you include `resources :users` in your routes.